# How to manage tables for users in my database?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Let's say i have a Teacher entity and a Student one. Both of them have email and password, but teacher have additional columns, as well as student. So, it will be different tables? But in this case,i will have do create authentification module, controller, jwt strategies and all the stuff for each of them. How to keep them in the same table, but extend depending on the role?

p.s. To clarify:

This is my PassportStrategy. And i need to use teacherService here. And same for Student. A lot of redundant code. And this is not the only case.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      usernameField: 'email'
    });
  }
  async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<Teacher | Student> {
    return this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser(email, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not create a user entity, and then have both teacher and student entities be linked to a single user entity via a foreign key? That would be closer to BCNF I think.

Comment: @SumnerEvans, I thought about this, it would be very nice, but i don't know how to link dynamically to specific table. Ok, i have BaseUser entity with email, password, role and foreign key to another table, that contains rest of columns. But i don't have only one entity. I have at least two: Student and Teacher. How to link User to specific table (student or teacher) based on their role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the specific data in a JSON column. That will keep you having one table for all teachers and students.

```js
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column({ type: 'json' })
    data: any;     //  <---------- The specific data goes into here.
}
```

**Update**

To apply `join`, they should be individual entities:

```js
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    role: 'teacher' | 'student';
}

class Student {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    userId: string;
    
    ...
}

class Teacher {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    userId: string;
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: but what if later i will want this data to have another join with other tables?

Comment: To join the tables, you would need to have them as individual tables. `User`, `Teacher` an d `Student`. `User` has a property called `role` and it can be `teacher` or `student`. And the `User` and `Teacher` entity has `userId` column.

Comment: And join User and Teacher/Student based on data (json) column? Will it work?

Comment: No. At this time, `data` wont exist. Let me update my answer

Comment: And how to join them then? As i know, relation decorator must be on both sides. And this is my problem: i don't know how to make generic column for both tables: student and teacher.